# if then else to return value in existing column

Tags: sql, ms-access, formula, ms-access-2016

In Access 2016 using SQL.  I need to add a new column called "Customer".  The value is based on if there is data in "Group Name" then use "Group Name".  If "Group Name" is blank then use the data in "Description".

This is what I'm trying to use and it's not working.

```
SELECT iIf(ISempty([group name])= FALSE,[Group name],[Description]) as Customer
```

The solution has to be using SQL as once it works in Access it is used in another software.  I am pretty new to this so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every database engine supports their own SQL flavor, and Access is a good example of this.  So even if you get this to work in Access, don't expect that it will just work in any other database without changes.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean here?  Error message?

Comment: from what table? missing the table name..

Comment: well if this is the exact code it looks like you miss-spelled the `iff()` function... I see a lowercase "L" there,

Comment: They software they use has them load a file and then run this script.  It uses the same SQL as Access.  I'm probably not using correct terminology, but I know if I can get it to work here that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The [IsEmpty Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx) *"Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been initialized."*

When you apply that function to your `[Group name]` field, it will always return False, which means this `IIf()` expression will always give you `[Group name]` ...

```sql
SELECT IIf(ISempty([group name])= FALSE,[Group name],[Description]) as Customer
```

You explained that you actually want `IIf()` to give you `[Group name]` when it is not Null, or `[Description]` otherwise.  To do that, you can substitute `IsNull()` for `IsEmpty()`:

```sql
SELECT IIf(IsNull([Group name])=False, [Group name], [Description]) As Customer
```

Here are a couple other ways to accomplish the same thing:

```sql
SELECT IIf([Group name] Is Null, [Description], [Group name]) As Customer
SELECT Nz([Group name], [Description]) As Customer
```

Oops!  You actually said *"blank"*, but I interpreted that to mean Null.  If blank could also mean an empty string, use this to give you `[Description]` when `[Group name]` contains either Null or an empty string ...

```sql
SELECT IIf(Len([Group name] & '') = 0, [Description], [Group name]) As Customer
```

Comment: When I use this a pop up box saying to Enter Parameter Value, Group Name.  I'm guessing from other responses that I need to add the table name??  It's AZDelta  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean what you showed us in your question was the entire query?  I thought it was just a piece of a query.  But, yes, you need at least something for the `FROM` ... to tell Access where the data comes from.

Comment: I have a couple other things I will add once I can get this to work.  I am brand new to this and have been asked to help.  I was hoping to get this one thing to work and go from there.  Would it be possible for you to send me the entire code I would need?  I really [really] appreciate it.

Comment: I will use what you have given me and try to go from there.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI SQL this can be done in two update statements:

```
-- First replace empty [Customer] with [Group Name]
Update [TargetTable] Set [Customer] = [Group Name]
Where [Customer] IS NULL OR [Customer] = '';

-- Then replace still empty [Customer] with [Description]
Update [TargetTable] Set [Customer] = [Description]
Where [Customer] IS NULL OR [Customer] = '';
```